# Json Deserialization BodyStyle Wrap issue using IPWorks nSoftware

Tags: servicestack, ipworks

I am using **IPWorks nsoftware** for creating service. In it, to call a service I am using

```
        Rest rest = new Rest();
        rest.Accept = "application/json";
        rest.ContentType = "application/json";
        rest.User = "UserName";
        rest.Password = "Password";
        rest.Get(@"http://Foo.com/roles.json");
        string result = rest.TransferredData;
        var listRoles = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<List<role>>(result);
```

I am getting the Json response as a string

> [{"role":{"name":"Administrator","created_at":"2012-02-11T09:53:54-02:00","updated_at":"2012-04-29T23:43:47-04:00","id":1"}},{"role":{"name":"NormalUser","created_at":"2013-02-11T08:53:54-02:00","updated_at":"2013-04-29T23:43:47-03:00","id":2"}}]

Here the json string contains my domain object “role” which  gets appended to my response (i.e the body style of the message is wrapped) .
I am using **ServiceStack.Text**’s Deserializer to convert the response string to my object. But since it’s wrapped, the deserilization is incorrect.

Is there anything that I am missing here ? Is there any “BodyStyle” attribute which could be added to the Rest request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GitHubRestTests shows some of the different ways](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/UseCases/GitHubRestTests.cs) you can deserialize a 3rd party json API with [ServiceStack's JSON Serializer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text).

If you want to deserialize it into typed POCOs then judging by your JSON payload the typed POCOs should look something like:

```
public class RolePermissionWrapper 
{
    public Role Role { get; set; }
    public Permission Permission { get; set; }
}

public class Role 
{ 
    public long Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public DateTime? Created_At { get; set; } 
    public DateTime? Updated_At { get; set; } 
} 

var listRoles = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<List<RolePermissionWrapper>>(result);
```